# In that vs with that

Tags: idiomatic-language

He seems to agree with most of us in that they're trying to conquer the world.

He seems to agree with most of us with that they're trying to conquer the world.

We say "agree with the idea", but in this context "in that" seems to be more appropriate, but I don't know exactly why I feel that way.

Comment: Do you mean "with that" or just "that"?  There are two different ideas here.  "He seems to agree with most of us, in that (he also believes for himself) they are trying to conquer the world".   This is explaining his independent beliefs which match the thoughts of the others........................................................"He seems to agree with most of us that they are trying to conquer the world".  This is explaining that he is part of the collective and thinks in unison.

Comment: Neither is correct. Remove the unwanted preposition ***in*** from the first one. The significance of *[statement 1] **in that** [statement 2]* is that *statement 1]* is only true ***to a limited extent.*** Specifically, that it's only true when considered ***from the perspective*** of *[statement 2]*. But in your example, *[statement 2]* is ***the actual belief*** that he and most of us share (we're not talking about something else being true ***from the perspective*** of that belief).

Comment: Most of us think that they're (whoever "they" are) trying to conquer the world. It would appear that he agrees with (most of) us. That's to say ***he thinks the same thing we do***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I disagree. The first sentence is common—at least as far as the usage I've heard and read. Although, typically, there would be a comma before the *in*. An alternative to *in that* is *insofar as*.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I guess we must just agree to disagree ***in that*** this usage is common. I don't endorse ***in*** there, or in OP's cited example.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica We can at least agree on the *second* sentence being wrong … even with a comma ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford: As you may know, I think the *only* reason for using commas is to reflect pauses in speech. And putting aside the issue of that disputed ***in***, I don't see that there ***has*** to be a pause in OP's example #1. It reads fine to me with or without. But I might use a *period* rather than a comma (it's likely to be a *long* pause! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I've always disagreed with that believe about the use of commas. It often *does* denote a pause, but there are very valid syntactical reasons for commas that have nothing to do with pauses. They indicate nonrestrictive information. The fact that such sentences can be read with a pause, doesn't mean that they always are, or that the pause isn't something in *addition* to the sense that it conveys.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica To add to that, I would pronounce the following sentences exactly the same—none of which having any additional pauses between any of the individual words. (1) *Iateanorangeanappleandacarrot* (2) *I ate an orange an apple and a carrot.* (3) *I ate an orange, an apple, and a carrot.* The fact that there are spaces and commas (or even a period at the end) doesn't make any difference in terms of how I read them out loud. The only functions of the spaces and the commas are related to syntax and comprehension.

Comment: Well, your *particular* example is an "Oxford comma", which many otherwise rigorously pedantic grammarians would accept as "optional" (whether "for any given context" or "for any given writer", I wouldn't know). Whatever - so far as I'm concerned, I'm sure the totality of my written output over a lifetime would have been better (more "comprehensible") if I'd used less commas.

Answer (score 0):

> He seems to agree with most of us in that they're trying to conquer the world.

This implies that he seems to agree with you, and "in that. . ." clarifies what exactly he agrees with you about.

> He seems to agree with most of us with that they're trying to conquer the world.

This is incorrect because "with that" is not a phrase that means something here. It tries to pull the word "that" in two mutually exclusive directions.

> He seems to agree with most of us with that.

This is fine. It would be better if it said "on that," but "with" is fine too.

"He seems to agree. . . that they're trying to conquer the world."
This is fine.

"That" serves as a noun in the first, and a connector in the second. When you combine the two, these contradict each other. The one word cannot be both.

In a sentence, "that" must be used *either* as a pronoun or subordinating conjunction, not both.

The second sentence is awkward because subordinating conjunctions do not generally follow prepositions like "with" to introduce clauses.

Also, "with most of us" is already functioning as the object of the verb "agree." Adding another "with" with is confusing. What is it supposed to be doing? The reader can't tell.